# Angular 7 FormArray rendering performance

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I am currently working on an angular component to render and modify an invoice. To edit the lineitems I am using a FormGroup with a FormArray of line item Forms:

```
lineItemForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    lineItems: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

When the lineitems are set via **@Input** to the component a **FormGroup** will be created for each lineitem.

```
set lineItems(lineItems: InvoiceLineItem[]) {
    this.lineItemForm.controls['lineItems'] = this.formBuilder.array(
        lineItems.map(lineItem => {
            return this.createLineItemForm(lineItem);
        })
    );
    this._lineItems = lineItems;
}

private createLineItemForm(lineItem: InvoiceLineItem): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        _id: [lineItem._id],
        number: [lineItem.number],
        amount: [lineItem.amount, Validators.compose([Validators.required, NumberValidator.validateNumber(2)])],
        title: [lineItem.title],
        netprice: [lineItem.netprice, Validators.compose([Validators.required, PriceValidator.validatePrice()])],
        netpriceTotal: [lineItem.netpriceTotal, Validators.compose([Validators.required, PriceValidator.validatePrice()])],
        grosspriceTotal: [lineItem.grosspriceTotal],
        taxrate: [lineItem.taxrate, Validators.compose([Validators.required, IntegerValidator.validateInteger()])],
        taxTotal: [lineItem.taxTotal],
        from: [lineItem.from, DateValidator.validateDate('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')],
        to: [lineItem.to, DateValidator.validateDate('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')],
        pageIndex: [],
        rowOrder: []
    });
}
```

**The template code looks like this (simplified):**

```
<div formArrayName="lineItems"
     *ngFor="let lineItem of lineItemForm.controls['lineItems'].controls; trackBy:getLineItemIdentity; let i = index; let even = odd">
  <div *ngFor="let column of alwaysVisibleColumns; trackBy:getColumnIdentity; let col = index; let f = first; let l = last;"
         [formGroupName]="i">
    <div [formControlName]="column.field" some-custom-directives...></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I am using divs as **formControls** (having custom directives to use them as content-editable inputs)

There are no problems whatsoever when there are like < 10 lineitems. Unfortunately the rendering process will block the UI for about 10s (!!!!!!) when there are like 30-40 lineitems on the invoice - which is absolutely ridiculous.

I am pretty sure the problem is all about the rendering of the individual formControls. When I remove them and just display plain text it will render much much faster.

So is there any way of improvement I can do on my side or do I have to wait until the angular team will improve it? Or will it never be usable for my scenario and I have to figure out some other solution?

> [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ODFnw5eECGiwurV7o6hMb3Imj7gg1D-l/view?usp=sharing) is a link to performance-measurement created by firefox dev-tools.

Comment: Can you please provide stackblitz url with minimal code. Would like to see custom directive and validator code

Comment: @AjayOjha I would love to give you a stackblitz example, but I won't be able to share you this highly propriertary code. Do u have any other questions or suggestions based on my initial question?

Comment: then remove the custom directives from the html and just bind the INPUT element with formControlName and see the performance, I am assuming that may be your custom directive code or validator code have problem. try to remove all and after that add one by one. this will help you to find the actual cause of the issue. Please let me know if you need my help in this.

Comment: @AjayOjha I did this in advance before posting this question. I am sure that the issues are coming from the fromControlName directive.

Comment: Cool, then log the issue in angular repo. But I am still not agree with the problem is from formControlName directive. Anyways. :)

Comment: @AjayOjha please see my answer, problem not solved, but not coming from the formControlName - you were right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of investigation and debugging I came to the conclusion that the performance issues are coming from a combination of multiple directives.

The FormControl by itself is not responsible for the delay I am experiencing. Instead I found out that calls to the Renderer(2) are making things really slow. Paired with some other more or less heavy computations led to this behavior. I just didn't expect that something like ".addClass" would cost like ~400ms in rendertime.

Comment: Problem is solved or not?, if not, then I would like to see the code one of your custom directive where you calling the addClass.

Comment: kind of solved since I now know where to investigate :). thanks for your help, but I cannot share the code